# Pausing the Python console

Tags: python, console

I am running some Python code in the console, inside a very long `for` loop. I would like to pause the execution of the script, and then be able to resume where I left. Is it possible to pause the Python console?

Note: I don't want to use `time.sleep`; I want to be able to externally pause the console in the middle of a loop.

Comment: It would help to know why you want to pause the console and what you need to do once the console is paused.

Comment: Then the Unix answers below apply.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: I'm automating testing that needs me to keep an eye on screens. Sometimes I want to go for a break and pause the tests.

Comment: Then ctrl-s/q should do the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're running python in a standard unix console, the usual ctrl-s (pause output, continue with ctrl-q) and ctrl-z (suspend, continue with fg) commands work. If you're running in a windows command shell, use the Pause button (press any key to continue).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Unix you can always Ctrl+Z, to go back to the command prompt and then 'fg' to get back to the python console.
On Windows use the Pause button

On Unix you can also do:

To stop:  kill -SIGSTOP pid

To continue: kill -SIGCONT pid

Answer (score 1):

If you know before runtime exactly when you will need to pause, just take a look at the pdb module.

If you do not know, I suggest you insert some code which checks for the existance of a certain file at every iteration and, if it exists, calls pdb. Performance, of course, will suffer. You can then create that file when you want to pause.

(file existance is simply an arbitrary condition which is easy-to-implement. You can choose others.)

Answer (score 1):

i think what your looking for is a command that will pause the code until you tell him to continue like hitting the Enter key

try putting

input()

where you want to "pause" the code

Comment: It seems the OP is not looking for a programming solution, hence the down votes.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop running windows 7 < ctrl + s > pauses execution.

Answer (score 0):

Win 10, python 3.5.1 shell: F10 toggles pause and run.